# How to setup phpunit with Jenkins on Openshift?

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit, openshift

I have been dealing with this problem for a long time now. I want to setup the framework phpunit with Jenkins on the Openshift cloud service.

I am not sure how to do it. I have been trying to search Google for some tutorials but I really can't find anything. I know this is a kind of broad question but I seriously need to solve it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this going easily by creating a jenkins application in OpenShift and then creating a php application in on OpenShift.

To create the jenkins app
`rhc app create -a jenkins jenkins-1`

Then create your php application
`rhc app create -a php php-5.4 --enable-jenkins'

Finally cd into your php app directory and configure phpunit.